# Overriding toString method in Scala Enumeration

Tags: scala, enums

How can I override "toString" to make this Scala code acts like the following Java code.

Code in Scala

```
object BIT extends Enumeration {
     type BIT = Value
     val ZERO, ONE, ANY = Value

     override def toString() =
       this match {
       case ANY => "x "
       case ZERO=> "0 "
       case ONE => "1 "
     }
}

val b = ONE
println(ONE)  // returns ONE
```

Wanted toString behaviour should produce same output as the following Java code.

```
public enum BIT {
    ZERO, ONE, ANY;

    /** print BIT as 0,1, and X */
    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
        case ZERO:
            return "0 ";
        case ONE:
            return "1 ";
        default://ANY
            return "X ";
        }
    }
}

BIT b = ONE;
System.out.println(b); // returns 1
```

I think I am overriding the wrong "toString" method.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, yes you are overriding the wrong toString method.  You're overriding the method on the `BIT` object itself, which is not very useful.

Second, you do this much easier by simply doing

```
object BIT extends Enumeration {
  type BIT = Value
  val ZERO = Value("0")
  val ONE = Value("1")
  val ANY = Value("x")
}
```

Then you can do

```
println(BIT.ONE) //prints "1"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the value and the string you can do it like this:

```
scala> object BIT extends Enumeration {
     |   type BIT = Value
     |   val ZERO = Value(0, "0")
     |   val ONE = Value(1, "1")
     |   val ANY = Value("x")
     | }
defined module BIT

scala> BIT.ZERO.toString
res2: String = 0

scala> BIT.ZERO.id
res3: Int = 0

scala> BIT.ANY.id
res4: Int = 2

scala> BIT.ANY.toString
res5: String = x
```